# How to identify an object in Selenium with No tags?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

In my code, I need to verify that the text "Product successfully added to your shopping cart" is displayed after adding an item to cart. Here is the screenshot, and also the element. As we can see, the text does not have a tag, i.e something like text="Product Added to your shopping cart". Its like just floating there on its own.

[image]

Here is the full xpath of this text object  : `//*[@id="layer_cart"]/div[1]/div[1]/h2/text()`

If I try to use this full path, I'm getting an error "object is text, it should be an element".

If I try to use until `"[@id="layer_cart"]/div[1]/div[1]/h2"`, and dont include the `'text()'`, I cannot get the text and verify, because its really not part of  the `<i>` tag. The result is just blank text. Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text **Product Added to your shopping cart** is a *Text Node* and is the **lastChild** of the parent `<h2>` node. So extract the text you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Python* and *cssSelector*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.layer_cart_product h2")))).strip())
  ```
- Using *Java* and *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'layer_cart_product')]//h2")))).toString());
  ```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But how did you know that that text was the "lastChild"? just want to understand more. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ronwald There are only 2 child nodes, an `<i>` node and a text node, where `<i>` node is the first child and text node is the last child.

Answer (score 1):

The text is not just floating there, it's part of the `<h2>` tag. using `text()` in the `xpath` returns a text node, which Selenium doesn't support. The second path you used is the correct path, although it's not a valid `xpath` right now

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='layer_cart']/div[1]/div[1]/h2"));
element.text // Product successfully added to your shopping cart
```