# xpath give nothing using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get `addresss` but they give me none value can you tell me what I make mistake in xpath kindy guide us  this is page link https://www.avocats-strasbourg.com/avocat?uid=3340

[image]

code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
webdriver_service = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service,options=options)
url = 'https://www.avocats-strasbourg.com/avocat?'
driver.get(url)
data=[]
def main():
    for x in range(44)[2:]:
        select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#edit-filter-ville'))))
        select.select_by_index(x)
        time.sleep(2)
        click_on_search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[@value="Lancer la recherche"])[1]')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", click_on_search_button)
        
        try:
            page_links = [element.get_attribute('href') for element in 
                          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.grid-3-small-1-tiny-1 a")))]
        except:
            pass
    
        for link in page_links:
            driver.get(link)
            time.sleep(2)
            
            try:
                address = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Adresse principale :')]/following-sibling::").text
                
            except:
                address=''
            print(address)
main()
```

Comment: Did you use to post before under a different username, `Amen Aziz`?

Comment: No I am not post

Comment: can you suggest solution what is correct xpath for these

Comment: See this answer. It will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59465575/3485434

Comment: I will try these `address=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Adresse principale :')]"))))`

Comment: but they gave me in output  is `Adresse principale : `

Comment: It's not the last child. It is also not the constant child number because the amount of elements there is changing from page to page.

Comment: @Prophet : It is possible using javascript executor, if you choose the correct css selector. Hope this answer helps.

Comment: @KunduK I tried your solution. It works correctly only on several pages, on most pages it returns empty string.

Comment: @Prophet : Can I have the page url where it is returning empty? I'll have a look.

Comment: Just run the entire OP code with your code line. Most of them not working. I walked thro 6-7 first pages, was only 1 fit.

Comment: @Prophet : As I said I don't have python, nor selenium in my PC, so I haven't tested. what I have checked, selected couple of dropdown values and check with chrome dev tool and it was working fine. Anyways looking for OP response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `javascript executor` and use following `css` selector.
I haven't run python scripts, however using Chome Dev tool and it is working fine.

```
address = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("h3 + span.sousgras").nextSibling.textContent')
```

[image]

Comment: thank it works but can you also tell me if I make the `css` selector for  `serment` and `case`  because both have same class

Comment: What is css selector for `case`

Comment: css Selector for `serment` is `span.sousgras.bloc100:nth-of-type(1)` and css selector for `case` is `span.sousgras.bloc100:nth-of-type(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the best way but anyway a way to get what you want in some way:

```
#creates a string with all the text inside the div
text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ficheavocat']").text
#creates a list with the lines splitted
textlist = text.splitlines()
#in this case the info you're looking for, the address, is the 6th element
address = textlist[6]
```

This is the result, the address variable:

> Adresse principale : 1 rue des Soeurs | 67400 ILLKIRCH-GRAFFENSTADEN

Then, of course, if you need, you can get rid of the *Adresse principale :* part